# How to select from a Query table returned by a stored procedure in ColdFusion?

Tags: loops, select, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I have a stored procedure which returns a bunch of queries and I need to select a few queries based on the information in two or more columns. I have used `cfloop query ="resultName"` before, but this time I cannot simply loop through it. Is this even possible?

**Code:**

```
<!--- Run procedure to generate result set/query --->
<cfstoredproc datasource="#XXX#" procedure="XXX">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="12" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="3" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="1" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT">

    <cfprocresult name="QueryU">
</cfstoredproc>
```

`QueryU` consists of a bunch of queries from which I want to select one column value based on two other column values.

**Update:**

The question is really, "how do I select a subset of records from an existing query?"

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will do, but I have to wait a few hours before it will allow me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the Adobe documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_r-s_22.html), you need to list a `cfprocresult` for each result set you are sending back.

```
<cfprocresult name="query1">
<cfprocresult name="query2">
<cfprocresult name="query3">
```

You can then reference the fields that you need while outputting each query.

Comment: the first vote on this answer put your reputation over 1000.  Congratulations on that.  Also, since it was my vote, you owe me a beer.

Comment: hah! :)  The question wasn't quite clear and could have been interpreted multiple ways, so I dont think my answer was quite what was being sought, but thanks!  Next time your in South FL, look me up!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a Query of Queries.

Here is an example based on [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=using_recordsets_3.html):

```
<!--- Run procedure to generate result set/query --->
<cfstoredproc datasource="#XXX#" procedure="XXX">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="12" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="3" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    <cfprocparam type="In" value="1" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT">

    <cfprocresult name="QueryU">
</cfstoredproc>

<!--- Run QoQ to get a subset of the results (dbtype=query, no data source) --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail"> 
    SELECT Emp_ID, FirstName, LastName
    FROM   QueryU
    WHERE  LastName =<cfqueryparam value="#LastNameSearch#" 
                 cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxLength="20">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Hope you do not mind, but I modified the example to show how it applied to your original code more clearly. If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back.